# Nested AND and OR querying a DataContext

Tags: c#, linq

I am not sure what is wrong with the following syntax. I would like to query my DataContext for the following data:

Show me everything that has nothing in FilesAccesses and nothing in FileAccessGroups.
Also show me everything that has my user ID in FilesAccesses.

Here is the syntax I am trying to use. It fails on the || at the end of the third line saying: "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'"

Is my syntax wrong? These types of queries have to be possible right?

```
return db.Files
  .Where(
    (f => !f.FilesAccesses.Any() && !f.FilesAccessGroups.Any()) ||
    (f => f.FilesAccesses.Any(a => a.UserId == user)))
  .OrderBy(f => f.ObjectType)
  .ThenBy(f => f.Name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, your syntax is indeed wrong.

```
return db.Files
  .Where(f =>
    (!f.FilesAccesses.Any() && !f.FilesAccessGroups.Any()) ||
    (f.FilesAccesses.Any(a => a.UserId == user)))
  .OrderBy(f => f.ObjectType)
  .ThenBy(f => f.Name);
```